# How do you mock a break statement in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I am having an issue with a LocalJumpError being raised when the example reaches the break statement.
Does anyone know how to stub out `break`, or if this is even the right approach?

**The Method:**

```
def foo(file_name, limit)
  CSV.foreach(file_name, col_sep: "|") do |row|
    row_count += 1
    do something...
    break if row_count >= limit
  end
end
```

**The Spec:**

```
it 'does not exceed the limit' do
  CSV.should_receive(:foreach).with(file_name, col_sep: "|") do |&block|
      block.call(header_fields)
      block.call(data)
  end
  foo(file_name, 2)
end
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what specifically you're trying to test here--are you trying to see if it stops after `limit` iterations?

Comment: Presumably the code in `do something...` results in side effects (for example, calling other methods or adding items to an array), against which you could make assertions to ensure that the `foreach` loop ran no more than `limit` times. If so, you don't need to worry about mocking `break` at all.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, I'm trying to make sure the limit is not exceeded.

Comment: @FMc: Yes, `do something` results in the processing of the line that is read from the file. I have tests for the processing, I just need this one last test to ensure the upper limit is not exceeded.

Comment: What do you do inside the loop? I'd probably try to latch on to something in there instead. Ideally the loop body would be self-contained and replaceable by a mock which could then be tested against.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Inside the loop, I just take the data from each line and create/update something in the database. I suppose I could just use a `while` loop, but I feel like I shouldn't avoid `break` statements just because I don't know how to test them.

Comment: The only way I can execute the code within the loop is to use `block.call` in the spec. But when I do this and exceed the limit, I get the LocalJumpError. I'm not sure how else to get the code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I might consider doing something like this as an integration-type test:

```
def foo(file_name, limit)
    CSV.read(file_name, col_sep: "|").each_with_index do |row, index|
      if index < limit
        #do something...
      end
    end
  end
end

it 'does not exceed the limit' do
  filename = 'path/to/file.csv'
  file = CSV.read(filename)
  file_length = file.size
  last_line = file.last

  output = foo(filename, file_length - 1)

  expect(output.last).to_not contain(last_line)
end
```

In this solution, you still iterate through every line of the CSV, but ignore the line if you're over the limit. It's not ideal, but it's one way to go.

The test would set the limit as one less than the file-length, then check if the last line got processed.

The assertion isn't quite right - it will depend on your `# do something` action.